# Static for loop? Performing calculations before

Tags: java

I'm feeling lost as to how to do this. I am trying to perform a calculation with a value that needs to be a global variable. but to be global it has to be static. I need the for loop to be static too so it can perform the calculation in the array but I can't remember how to do this. 
The very last line of code is where I am stuck currently due to "Cannot find symbol" errors. I am trying to find a way to bring yVal0 in to this method so I can perform the calculation

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RegressionGUI  extends JFrame
    implements ActionListener {
private JLabel VariableLabel = new JLabel("Select one independent Variable");
```

Comment: Trust me, there is no need to make anything static here, so you must re-think things so as not to need to use this kludge.

Comment: Is all of this code in one class?  If so you can define an instance variable to contain your "global" data.  Ie, you can make your `yVal...` values instance variables.  (Though I suspect there would be better ways to code all this if one had the inclination to disentangle it.)

Comment: Also, you need to explain to us just what you're trying to do with this code. What is it trying to accomplish?

Comment: Apologies, I'm new to programming. (1st year at Uni) only been doing programming for about 3-4 weeks now. I'm trying to create a regression calculator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, I doubt that you need to use static anything, and a quick review of your (poorly formatted) code suggests that this is still so. Why not instead make some of your numeric variables class fields and not method-local or constructor-local so you can use them in any non-static method of the class?

e.g.,

```
public class RegressionGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
   private JLabel VariableLabel = new JLabel("Select one independent Variable");
   private JButton X1btn = new JButton("Number of Bathrooms (X1)");
   private JButton X2btn = new JButton("Area of the site (X2)");
   private JButton X3btn = new JButton("Size of living space (X3)");
   private JButton X4btn = new JButton("Number of Garages (X4)");
   private JButton X5btn = new JButton("Number of Rooms (X5)");
   private JButton X6btn = new JButton("Number of bedrooms (X6)");
   private JButton X7btn = new JButton("Age (X7)");
   private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
   private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

   // **** added these guys
   private double[] xValues = new double[4];
   private double[] yValues = new double[4];
```

Comment: Thank you everyone, your help has been incredibly useful. I just had myself confused (as you can tell by the way its formatted) and Hovercraft Full Of Eels has provivided an excellent solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's horribly formatted your code is hard to follow (and thus I didn't read it), but if you want a static variable to be computed at runtime, your best bet is something like this:

```
public static final int MY_VAR = computeValue();

private static int computeValue() {
    //for loop here
}
```

Comment: Again, why would his program need this? As per my comment to Adam, I wonder if your answer answers his *question* but doesn't solve his *problem*.

Comment: @Hovercraft: I don't know why *his program* would need this, because as I said in my answer I refused to read it.  I answered the issue that he described in the first paragraph and ignored the code.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a [static initialization block](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).  This is a block of code that is executed just before the first time an object of the class is initialized, or just before the first time a static member of the class is executed.

Comment: Why would his code/program need this? I think that your answer answers his *question* but does not solve his *problem*.